# JavaScript Conundrum

Tags: javascript

I want to move a JavaScript function up to the `<script>` tag from a input tag and it's not working.

This works:

```
<input type="text" name="aaa" id="aaa" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=
  this.value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+
    this.value.substring(1,this.value.length);
  if (this.value=='') 
    document.getElementById('aaaLabel').innerHTML='AAA';"
/>
```

This doesn't:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function FieldOnKeyUp() {
    this.value=this.value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+
      this.value.substring(1,this.value.length);
    if (this.value=='') 
      document.getElementById('aaaLabel').innerHTML='AAA'; 
  }
</script>
```

---

```
<input type="text" name="aaa" id="aaa" onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp()">
```

What's the difference?

Comment: I really want to +1 for your use of 'conundrum'.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please give a reason so that the OP can improve the question. Simple down-voting does not help. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Comment: I would guess if you look in the javascript log, you'll see errors.

Comment: Perhaps the difference is that by moving the JavaScript code you've changed the definition of `this`.  You may have better luck of you do `onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)"`, and then use `function FieldOnKeyUp(theField)` to declare your function.  Then replace every instance of `this` with `theField`.

Comment: Yea, I don't understand why I'm getting down voted, but I also don't remember how to make these code blocks look nicer when the post... Is it clear what I'm asking?

Comment: @aroth - Yes it has to be that.

Comment: @aroth Make your comment an answer and provide a fiddle for some upvotes.  Aside: I don't understand the downvotes on the question either.

Comment: aroth is correct, but I'm a JS beginner... I tried those instructions and ended up with some weird bug that I didn't get when I had the JS in the input tag. The bug doubles the first entered character. Any idea?

Comment: Disregard that last bit. It works. Thanks aroth.

Comment: As an aside, don't use `javascript:`. It's evil. Just use `onkeyup="this.value...` when you want to do things the "right" wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `this` is not passed to your separate function.  In fact, `this` in your function is set to the `window` object.  You need to change to this type of code in order to pass the right value to your function:

```
<input type="text" name="aaa" id="aaa" onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)">
```

and your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function FieldOnKeyUp(el) {
     el.value=el.value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+el.value.substring(1); 
     if (el.value=='') {
         document.getElementById('aaaLabel').innerHTML='AAA'; 
     }
}
</script>
```

Here's a sample that shows this code working: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2dJ6x/.